# run a function after another with first data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run 2 function where one is called inside the other.

I have a function and inside it I call a second function. I want to use the data from the second function in the first one.

```
function addLine() {
     if (ContagemAntesIntegracao == '' || !ContagemAntesIntegracao) {
        ContagemAntesIntegracao = 0;
    }
    var AfetaStock = '0';
    verify_serialnumbers().complete(function (data){....
```

and the function that is runing inside:

```
function verify_serialnumbers() {
  ....if (ArrayErros.length > 0) {
                set_errors(ArrayErros);
                ArrayErros = undefined;
                return;
            }
...
            var Link = $('#LINK').val() + '/?action=_ajax_inventory';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: Link,
                dataType: 'json',
                placeholder: 'Lote',
                data: {
                    CheckSerialNumbers: '1',
                    CodArmazem: CodArmazem,
                    CodProduto: CodProduto,
                    CodLocalizacao: CodLocalizacao,
                    ArrayNumerosSerie: ArrayNumerosSerie,
                }
                }).done(function (response) {
                    if (response != 'ok')
                    {
                         set_errors(dados);
                    }else{
                        return ArrayNumerosSerie;
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

How can I continue inside the first one with an array that does not come from the AJAX call?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: `verify_serialnumbers` doesn't seem to return anything, so you can't call `verify_serialnumbers().complete`

Comment: but if i put a return it wont work with complete() either.

Comment: Yes, you have to return something that has a `.complete` method. [Like the jqXHR object that `$.ajax()` returns](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). However, I'm not sure if that's what you intend here.

Comment: i want to run the function that has the ajax, and i want to keep runing acode after that function is done, thats my objective